# VBA Printer Settings

Tags: vba, ms-access, printers

Hello how can I retrieve a list of the Current PC printers from system settings and show them on a form and let the user choose one to set as default printer using VBA MS Access?

Answer (score 0):

`Application.Printers`!

As per documentation: Returns the Printers collection representing all the available printers on the current system. Read-only Printers collection.

And `Application.Printer` for setting new default.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.printers
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.printer